# asp.net shopping cart inventory management in case of multi user environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

is there any need to handle locks in terms of threading in any inventory application.
like as i think asp.net is not thread safe.

lets say that there is a product available and its quantity available is 1 and number of user partially trying to book that particular product are 40. so which is going to get that product. or what happens.

not sure even if the question is reliable or not.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benchr/archive/2008/09/03/does-asp-net-magically-handle-thread-safety-for-you.aspx

i am not sure on this please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, technically, you're not even talking about ASP.NET here, but rather Entity Framework or whatever else you're using to communicate with SQL Server or whatever else persistent data store you're using. Relational databases will typically row-lock, so that as one client is updating the row, the row cannot be read by another client, but you can still run into concurrency issues.

You can handle this situation one of two ways: pessimistic concurrency or optimistic concurrency. With pessimistic concurrency you create locks and any other thread trying to read/write the same data is simply turned away in the mean time. In a multi-threaded environment, it's far more common to use optimistic concurrency, since this allows a bit of play room for failover.

With optimistic concurrency, you version the data. As a simplistic example, let's say that I'm looking for the current stock of widgets in my `dbo.Widgets` table. I'd have a column like `Version` which might initially be set to "1" and 100 widgets in my `Stock` column. Client one wants to buy a widget, so I read the row and note the version, 1. Now, I want to update the column so I do an update to set `Stock` to 99 and `Version` to 2, but I include in my where clause `Version = 1`. But, between the time the row was initially read and the update was sent, another client bought a widget and updated the version of the row to 2. The first client's update fails, because `Version` is no longer 1. So the application then reads the row fresh and tries to update it again, subtracting 1 from `Stock` and incrementing `Version` by 1. Rinse and repeat. Generally, you'll want to have some upward limit of attempts before you'll just give up and return an error to the user, but in most scenarios, you might have one collision and then the next one goes through fine. Your server would have to be getting slammed with people eagerly trying to buy widgets before it would be a real problem.

Now of course, this is a highly simplistic approach, and honestly, not something you really have to manage yourself. Entity Framework, for example, will handle concurrency for you automatically as long as you have a rowversion column:

```
[Timestamp]
public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
```

See http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application for the full guide to setting it up.

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET certainly is not Thread Safe. The article you link too is fine as a start, but doesn't tell all the story by a long way. In your case, you likely load the Product List into memory at first request for it, or at Application Startup or some other trigger.

When a Request wants to work with a product you grab the appropriate member of this preloaded list. (Believe me this is better than having every request loading the product or product list from the database.) However, now if you have 40 simultaneous requests for the same product they will all be accessing the same object, and new nasty things can happen, like ending up with -39 stock.

You can address this in a many ways ways, but they boild down to two:

- Protect the data somehow
- Do what Amazon does

**Protect the data**
There are numerous ways of doing this. One would be to use a critical section via the Lock keyword on C#. For an example, something like this in the Product Class:

```
private object lockableThing; // Created in the ctor
public bool ReduceStockLevelForSale(int qtySold)
{
    bool success = false;
    if (this.quantityOnHand >= qtySold)
    {
        lock (lockableThing)
        {
            if (this.quantityOnHand >= qtySold)
            {
                this.quantityOnHand -= qtySold;
                success = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return success;
}
```

The double check on the quantity on hand is deliberate and required. There are any number of ways of doing the equivalent. Books have been written about this sort of thing.

**Do what Amazon does**
As long as at some point in the Order Taking sequence, Amazon thinks it has enough on hand (or maybe even any) it will let you place the order. It doesn't reduce the stock level while the order is being confirmed. Once the order has been confirmed, it has a back-end process (i.e. NOT run by the Web Site) which checks order by order that the order can be fulfilled, and only reduces the On Hand level if it can. If it can't be, they put the order on hold and send you an email saying 'Sorry! We don't have enough of Product X!' and giving you some options.

**Discussion**
Amazon's is the best way, because if you decrement the stock from the Web Site at what point do you do it? Probably not until the order is confirmed. If the stock has gone, what do you then do? Also, you are going to have to have some functionality to send the 'Sorry!' email: what happens when the last one (or two or three) items of that product can't be found, don't physically exist or are broken? You send a 'Sorry!' email.

However, this does assume that you are in control of the full order to dispatch cycle which is not always the case. If you aren't in control of the full cycle, you need to adjust to what you are in control of, and then pick a method.